# SuperPutty Commands dialog box updates all terminals

Tags: superputty

I'm looking for the setting to restrict the SuperPutty "Commands" dialog box to work for only shown terminals.  Right now, when I type in a command it works on all the terminals.  I want to change it so the command only works on terminal windows that are visible.